# Gradle project sync failed after upgrade to Android Studio 2.2.2

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization, project

*Basic functionality (eg. editing,debugging)will not work properly.   Error:Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0*

I recently updated my android studio on stable channel and since then all my old project files have this issue when i open them

on the gradle console -> Messages

Error:**Unexpeced lock protocol found in lock file . Expected 3,found 0.**

Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: Invalidate caches/Restart ?

Comment: @Nongthonbam i tried it bro .. didnt work :( !!..... but i  found the fix .. check it out

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the fix :

You just need to go to File -> Project Structure or jus press **Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S**

and then on the top left click **Project** Make sure that your **Android Plugin Version** is the same as you **Android Studio Version** .. This should fix it

additionally

You can also create a new Project and check under Project view initially you'll be in Android .. change the view to ... Project - > gradle (Note .. not .gradle only gradle ) ->wrapper ->gradle-wrapper properties.. open this file and you can see the last line ie ..

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

make sure you have the same gradle version in your old files as well

Check out this Youtube Video i made regarding this issue

https://youtu.be/-Ngn4YvbKtw